# Process queues at different rates in shared codebase

Tags: microservices, publish-subscribe

I'm managing an autoscalable service (gke) that consumes from various queues (processing across queues shares 95% of the same business logic). We want to scale up consumption on these queues differently due to each having different load/SLA. For each queue, we want to process data within a range; ie don't go below x rps nor above y rps.

Any idea of a good way to achieve this?